# Excel button VBA not working in 64 bit Excel 2016

Tags: excel, button

I have been using 32 bit MS Excel and this Macro worked fine. Now I have moved to 64 bit Excel 2016 and macro is not working. What is the problem with it? Is there a solution to get it work with both 32 bit and 64 bit versions?

```
Sub Rectangle_Clicked()
    Button = Application.Caller
    Rectangle_Toggle (Button)
End Sub
Sub Rectangle_Toggle(Button As Variant)
    With Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes(Button)

        'Transparency of the shape 1 = transparent, 0 = solid
        .Fill.Transparency = 1
        'Hides the cell's value
        Range(.TopLeftCell.Address).Font.Color = Range(.TopLeftCell.Address).Interior.Color

        If .TextFrame.Characters.Text = Chr$(252) Then
         .TextFrame.Characters.Text = ""
         .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
         Range(.TopLeftCell.Address).Value = False
        Else
        .TextFrame.Characters.Text = Chr$(252)
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(46, 208, 80)    '(50, 195, 50)  <-- change your color here
        Range(.TopLeftCell.Address).Value = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I am getting an error "Can't find project in library". And VB highlights word button in `Button = Application.Caller`

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working".

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: Chr$(252) runs smoothly on my 64 bit excel. Exactly what line is throwing an error?

Comment: I have edited my post again. So I use code as in my original post.. Then I get an error message and it highlights word "Button"

Comment: What references do you have checked in the VBA project? I'll bet one of them is listed as 'MISSING:'

Comment: There is one "MISSING". It reads that "MISSING: Microsoft Windows Common Controls-2 6.0 (SP6)
My macro is however for shape = rectangle that is working as a checkbox.

Comment: Ok. I just unchecked MISSING reference and it seems to work fine again! Thank you Rory!

Comment: Uncheck that reference. They aren't compatible with 64bit Excel anyway.